# How do I implement WrapWithOverflow like behaviour on TextBlocks for Windows Phone development?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, expression-blend

I'm working in Expression Blend 4 and developing for Windows Phone 7.1. I would like to implement for the `Wrap` property something like `WrapWithOverflow` however this option is only available in WPF according to the Blend Help files - the only behaviours that are available are `Wrap` and `NoWrap`.

`WrapWithOverflow` wraps words onto a new line but if a word is longer than the `TextBlock` it will clip it short rather than breaking the word onto a newline.

How would I implement this using XAML and preferably using Blend?

Answer (score 0):

So I have a kind of a workaround.

1. Set a clipping path. Do this by creating a `Rectangle` the same size as the `TextBlock`, selecting the `TextBlock` first then Ctrl selecting the `Rectangle` second and choosing 'Object -> Path -> Make Clipping Path'.
2. Create an `IValueConverter` on the code-behind in Visual Studio (since the text is databound). If the text is not data bound then format manually. The converter inserts newlines in place of spaces - this is not ideal for various reasons but is good enough for my purposes. The code I ended up with is shown at the bottom.
3. Insert the `IValueConvertor` in the advanced section of the binding dialogue.

```
public class WordsOnNewlines : System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        string s = (string)value;
        return s.Replace(" ", System.Environment.NewLine);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        return null;    
    }
}
```